# can't perform a react state update on an unmounted component. this is a no-op but it indicates a memory leak

Tags: javascript, react-native, memory-leaks, geolocation

Warning: Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application. To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in the componentWillUnmount method.

```
componentDidMount() {
    this.RetrieveSellerNo();
    this.requestLocationPermission();
    this.requestData();
    this.Watch();

    this._interval = setInterval(() => {


        if (this.state.SellerNo !== null) {
            this.uploadPosition();
        }
        this.requestData();
    }, 60000);
    setTimeout(() => {
        this.requestData();
        this.StoreiposLat();
        this.StoreiposLong();
    }, 5000);
}

componentWillUnmount = () => {
    Geolocation.clearWatch(this.watchId);

}



Watch = () => {
    this.watchId = Geolocation.watchPosition(
        (position) => {
            this.setState({
                watch: {
                    lat: position.coords.latitude,
                    long: position.coords.longitude
                }
            });
        },
        (error) => {
            // console.log(error.message)
        },
        { enableHighAccuracy: false, timeout: 20000, maximumAge: 1000, } //distanceFilter:1
    );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your timeout and/or interval is probably still running and attempting to update the state even after the component was unmounted. You are not clearing the interval and the timeout created in componentDidMount.

Store the timeout just like you are storing the interval. In you componentDidMount:

```
this._timeout = setTimeout(...)
```

Then, in your componentWillUnmount, do the following:

```
Geolocation.clearWatch(this.watchId)
clearInterval (this._interval)
clearTimeout(this._timeout)
```

Comment: is this ok? setTimeout(()=>{ this.props.navigation.replace('Search'); clearTimeout(); },500) or we must use componentWillUnmount in everywhere we have Timeout ?

Comment: No that will not solve the issue. The callback is fired after the timeout has elapsed, so that clearTimeout() has no effect whatsoever. You should clear the timeout on unmount, by using componentWillUnmount. If you don't like this approach (which I don't either), I would suggest looking into using React Hooks. Hooks are a new way of writing components and they don't use the rather ugly componentDidMount, componentWillUnmount etc.

Answer (score 0):

I did it . But there is still an error.
I used pureComponent and clearing all timeout and interval.

I have to say that this happens when I go from this page to the login page and come back to the this page.

Each time the amount of RAM is increased and added to the previous value.

Comment: is this ok? setTimeout(()=>{
              this.props.navigation.replace('Search');
              clearTimeout();
            },500)                                        or we must use componentWillUnmount in everywhere we have Timeout ?